# Ubuntu software updater installation

Tags: software-installation

I just installed Ubuntu in a virtual machine, and I can't find the software updater.

I tried `sudo apt-get install update-manager`, and it said it has been installed already.

Comment: Which version if Ubuntu? There is no such package like "update-manage". Please [edit] to make your question clear.

Answer (score 1):

Type `up` in the Dash and click the Software Updater icon to launch the Software Updater, or open the terminal and run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` to update the software from the terminal,

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing and reinstalling Update Manager. Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo apt remove update-manager && sudo apt update && sudo apt install update-manager
```

If you are still unable to find its icon, you can launch it from terminal:

```
sudo update-manager
```

Here's how its icon look like:

[image: Update manger]